# Did gzip destroy my log file?

Tags: linux, unix, gzip

I had a rather big log file. So I thought I'd gzip it before transferring it to my pc.
I did

```
gzip bla.log
```

which gave me a tiny

```
bla.log.gz
```

When I extract it using

```
gunzip bla.log.gz
```

I get back to my bla.log, but it's small and when I open it with vi it looks like this:

```
 ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Why did this happen? Is there a way I can get my log file from this .gz archive?

And BTW I'm on a Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Had the process logging to the file finished with it before you compressed it?   If file was still open in a process, the process can still write to the file even if you change the name.

Comment: That's a good question. The process of zipping went really quick, way to quick for a >2GB text file, so I new something was fishy. In the end we restored the file from the backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's odd.

Exactly how small is it?  How big was the original log file?  What does `file bla.log.gz` say?

Normally `gzip bla.log` will write `bla.log.gz` and then, if that was successful, delete `bla.log`.  `gunzip blo.log.gz` will write `bla.log` and then delete `bla.log.gz`.

If something goes wrong during the `gzip` command (say, it ran out of space, exceeded your quota, was killed by a signal, or the computer lost power), then you could easily end up with a partial or corrupted `bla.log.gz` file -- but then the original `bla.log` file should still be there.

And if you then run `gunzip bla.log.gz`, you *should* get a prompt like:

```
gzip: bla.log already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?
```

It *shouldn't* have clobbered your original `bla.log` file unless (a) you told it to (by using `gunzip -f` or by anwering `y` to the above prompt), or (b) it successfully generated `bla.log.gz`.

To answer your question, if `bla.log.gz` consists of nothing more than a few zero bytes, you're not going to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: I really don't know what happend. I asked the guy to restore the file from the backup and the second try worked the way you describe. BTW, the bla.log was about >2GB big

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should not happen. Try to read the gz file with a tool like gzless or something. If this is also screwed. Something went wrong while compression.